# What app is featured in Apple's Chase ad?

Tags: apple-watch, activity.app

This Apple ad shows an Apple Watch app that lets you compete with friends. What app is this? My guess is that it is some third party app since other ads feature third party apps but others say it is a leak of upcoming Apple Watch functionality.

[YouTube: Apple Watch — Chase](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UXTlCWuc_fs)

> Ready to start a rivalry? Apple Watch lets you set fitness goals and
>   compete against family and friends.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I read on a different site that it's **Argus**: Argus - Calorie Counter & Activity Tracker for Heart Healthy Diet & Living by Azumio Inc.
https://appsto.re/us/KlOnL.i